# snmpwalk command did return different number of variable bindings

Tags: snmp

I run the command below in my linux environment.

snmpwalk -t 10000000 -v2c -cpublic localhost:161 1 >abc.txt

The problem is i always get different number of variable bindings!! What is happening? Any solution?

Comment: Learn the standard, and you will see this is absolutely normal. The  objects are dynamic, not static.

Comment: Hi Lex, this object will always increase even i did not perform any installation / add on to the control environment? I perform my testing on the vmware image running at my local machine.

Comment: Please find what are added, as for dynamic tables, even if you don't make significant changes on the system, it can increase or decrease according to its own nature.